# Query getting executed but shows error

Tags: php

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $p (q,o1,o2,o3,o4,ta,ma) VALUES ('$q','$o1','$o2','$o3','$o4','$ta','$ma')";
```

this query is getting executed but shows error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near '(q,o1,o2,o3,o4,ta,ma) VALUES
 ('','','','','','','')' at line 1
```

any idea??

Comment: Enclose the `$p` under single quotes. Like.. `INSERT INTO '$p'`

Comment: Does $p actually have a value to it?

Comment: Nope, then it doesnt even execute.

Comment: Yes it has a value, I am saying that the "query is getting executed".

Comment: Now I am getting  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the rIght syntax to use near ''ss' (`q`,`o1`,`o2`,`o3`,`o4`,`ta`,`ma`) VALUES ('Various terms of' at line 1"

Comment: what `echo $sql` says?

Comment: Sorry it was my own fault, page was redirecting to itself which was giving empty values to the query, anyways thanks for the swift responses...

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
$sql=" INSERT INTO '$p' ( `q` , `o1` ,`o2` ,`o3` , `o4` ,`ta` ,`ma`) VALUES ('$q','$o1','$o2','$o3','$o4','$ta','$ma') "
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes for   '$p'

```
$sql="INSERT INTO '$p' (`q`,`o1`,`o2`,`o3`,`o4`,`ta`,`ma`) VALUES ('$q','$o1','$o2','$o3','$o4','$ta','$ma')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use single comma on php variable if you are using double comma at the start. Like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'table' WHERE 'user' = '$user'";
```

in your case:

```
" INSERT INTO '$p' ( `q` , `o1` ,`o2` ,`o3` , `o4` ,`ta` ,`ma`) VALUES ('$q','$o1','$o2','$o3','$o4','$ta','$ma') "
```